# Unity: minimap cam with visual cue for location

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, fly

I use a flycam to move freely on a vast terrain, then I have a Minimap using a secondary 2d camera in a top position. But then I need a "dot" or some visual cue to know where the camera is in relation to the map. I've tried several things with no success. Any ideas to show a dot in the position of the flycam to be able to follow it from the top 2d cam?

Comment: When you say "dot" do you mean a "point" or a position shown in world space? And you want to know where that position is on the mini map? Also show any scripts you use for the minimap.

Comment: If you just need an indicator for the position of this flycam relative to the whole map, since the minimap is displayed with the downward facing camera (which i'm assuming is set to orthographic), you can just attach a circle sprite child `GameObject` to the flycam that's facing the camera and directly above the flycam all the time

Comment: the sprite trick is the first one I tried but doesn't work properly, because the fly cam goes up and down and rotate in all directions so the sprite losses the functionality.